# Geometric Fixed Points of Thom Spectrum

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, equivariant-topology

Recall that the Thom spectrum is an orthogonal spectrum $\operatorname{mO} \in \mathbf{Sp}$ defined via $\operatorname{mO}(V) = \operatorname{Th}(\operatorname{Gr}_{\dim{V}}(V \oplus  \mathbb{R}^{\infty}))$ where this means that we take the Thom Space of the universal bundle.

Let $G$ be a finite group, $\rho_G = \mathbb{R}[G]$ be the regular representation and $\overline{\rho}_G = \left \{\sum_g a_g g : \sum_g a_g = 0 \right \}$ be the reduced regular representation. Then,
$$ \operatorname{mO}(V \otimes \rho_G) = \operatorname{Th}(\operatorname{Gr}_{|G| \dim{V}}((V \otimes \rho_G) \oplus \mathbb{R}^{\infty})) \cong \operatorname{Th}(\operatorname{Gr}_{|G| \dim{V}}(V \oplus \mathbb{R}^{\infty} \oplus (V \otimes \overline{\rho}_G))). $$
Then, I want to understand the following (which is essentially Example 6.1.46 in Stefan Schwede's *Global Homotopy Theory*).

**Claim.** Let $V$ be an inner product space. An element $[x,U] \in \operatorname{mO}(V \otimes \rho_G)$ is $G$-fixed if and only if $x \in U^G$ and $U = U^G \oplus (U \cap (V \otimes \overline{\rho}_G))$.

This sounds like the following elementary group representation theory statement: Let $V \oplus W$ be a $G$-representation such that $G$ acts trivially on $V$ and $W^G = 0$. Let $U \subseteq V \oplus W$ be a linear subspace. Then, $U$ is $G$-fixed if and only if $U = U^G \oplus (U \cap W)$.

But the converse is wrong.

So I seem to be missing something. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to respond to questions in the comments**

As you observe, the claim is incorrect. Note though that this claim is not used in Example 6.1.46 of Stefan Schwede's book. What is used is only one direction: if $U \subseteq V \oplus W$ is $G$-invariant, with $V$ and $W$ as above, then $U = (U \cap V) \oplus (U \cap W)$ as subsets of $V \oplus W$.

I claim that it follows from this that there is a homeomorphism
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{Gr}(V) \times \mathbf{Gr}(W)^G \cong \mathbf{Gr}(V \oplus W)^G.
\end{aligned}
There is a map $\mathbf{Gr}(V) \times \mathbf{Gr}(W)^G \to \mathbf{Gr}(V \oplus W)^G$ given by sending $(U',U'')$ to $U := U' \oplus U''$. Since $V$ has trivial action, any $U'$ is automatically $G$-invariant. As $U''$ is $G$-invariant by assumption, $U$ is also $G$-invariant, so the map is well-defined. There is also a map $\mathbf{Gr}(V \oplus W)^G \to \mathbf{Gr}(V) \times \mathbf{Gr}(W)^G$ given by sending $U$ to $(U^G,U \cap W)$, which is just another way of writing $(U \cap V, U \cap W)$. Both $U \cap V$ and $U \cap W$ are $G$-invariant. It is clear that you get back $(U',U'')$ from $U' \oplus U''$ by doing this. However, what is a priori not clear (which I overlooked in my previous post) is whether any $U$ is the same as $(U \cap V) \oplus (U \cap W)$. Since you say in the comments that you're already fine with this, we're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bastiaan. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but isn't the point exactly that not every linear subspace $U \subseteq V \oplus W$ can be written as $(U \cap V) \oplus (U \cap W)$? Take for example $V = W = \mathbb{R}$ and $U = \langle (1,1) \rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: You're right, that was silly! I now understand your question, and I have to say I'm also confused by it right now...

Comment: So at least for finite groups, I think you can argue as follows: given $x \in U$, consider $x' = \frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert}\sum_{g \in G} gx$ and $x'' = x - x'$. Then $x \in U^G \subseteq V$ and $x'' \in U \cap V^{\perp} = U \cap W$. Furthermore, $x = x' + x''$. So every $G$-equivariant $U$ must be $U^G \oplus (U \cap W)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: I agree that every $G$-equivariant $U$ must be of the form $U^G \oplus (U \cap W)$, even though I can't quite follow your argument. How does it follow does $x'' \in U \cap V^{\perp}$? (But I also have a proof which looks similar in spirit.)

Comment: But unfortunately, the converse seems to be wrong. (Take e.g. in $\mathbb R^3$ the decomposition $V = \text{$z$-axis}$ and $W = \text{$(x,y)$-plane}$ and let $C_3$ act on $V \oplus W$ by $\frac{2 \pi i}{3}$-rotation on $W$. Take $U$ as any non-trivial subspace of $W$.) And I think Schwede wants both directions which he uses to obtain a splitting $\bigvee_{j \geq 0} \operatorname{Th} \left( \operatorname{Gr}_{|V|+j}(V \oplus \mathbb{R}^{\infty}) \right) \wedge \operatorname{Gr}_j(V \otimes \overline{\rho}_G)_+^G \cong \operatorname{mO}(V \otimes \rho_G)^G$.

Comment: If we take for granted the fact that any $G$-invariant $U$ is of the form $U^G \oplus (U \cap W)$, then I don't understand what is left to do. Haven't we now written every $U$ uniquely as $U' \oplus U''$ for arbitrary $U' \subseteq V$ and $G$-invariant $U'' \subseteq W$, giving the homeomorphism? I don't follow what you mean by 'converse'.

Comment: Don't we need to check that every $U$ of the form $U^G \oplus (U \cap W)$ is also $G$-invariant?

Comment: My response didn't fit here, so I've updated my answer. But the point is: yes, we do need to check that every $U$ of the form $U' \oplus U''$ with arbitrary $U' \subseteq V$ and $G$-invariant $U'' \subseteq W$ is again $G$-invariant, but this is easy. I might be missing your point though.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It looks good now, thank you!